# Вопросы по якорям регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

1. Чем отличаются якоря начала строки `^` и начала текста `\A` я думал второй действует только на буквы, но нет, он и пробел и символы видит.
2. Такой же вопрос про конец строки `$` и конец текста `\Z`
3. В PHP работают регулярки с якорями на начало слова `/<` и конец слова `/>`? Т.к. тест показывает что он просто видит тег https://regex101.com/r/Ly86wY/1

Comment: Посмотрите модификатор регулярок `m` (multiline) когда он включен `^` ловит все начала строк, даже если их в тексте много https://regex101.com/r/24N9pB/1  А `\A` это действительно начало текста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Чем отличаются якоря начала строки ^ и начала текста \A я думал второй действует только на буквы, но нет, он и пробел и символы видит.*

Якорные метасимволы и другие «проверки с нулевой длиной совпадения» совпадают не с реальными символами, а с позициями в тексте.

#### Начало физической или логической строки: ^, \A

Метасимвол **^** совпадает в начале текста, в котором производится поиск, или в расширенном режиме привязки к границам строк *(при использовании модификатора **m**)* - в позиции после любого символа новой строки. Метасимвол **\A** *(если он поддерживается)* совпадает только в начале текста, независимо от режима поиска.

> *Такой же вопрос про конец строки $ и конец текста \Z*

#### Конец физической или логической строки: $, \Z, \z

Концепция «конца строки» несколько сложнее парной ей концепции начала строки. В разных реализациях **$** интерпретируется по-разному. В самом распространенном варианте он совпадает с концом целевого текста перед завершающим символом новой строки. Это сделано для того, чтобы выражения вида `~s$~` *(«строка,заканчивающаяся символом **s**»)* совпадали с комбинациями символов `~…s\n~` в тексте, когда строки завершаются буквой s и символом новой строки.

Выбор режима может повлиять на интерпретацию $, в результате он будет соответствовать любым промежуточным символам новой строки в блоке текста.

Метасимвол **\Z** *(если он поддерживается)* соответствует метасимволу **$** в стандартном режиме, что означает совпадение в конце текста или перед символом новой строки, завершающим текст. Парный метасимвол **\z** совпадает только в конце строки, без учета возможных символов новой строки.

> *В PHP работают регулярки с якорями на начало слова /< и конец слова />? Т.к. тест показывает что он просто видит тег*

#### Границы слов: \b, \B

В PHP для обозначения границы слова используется последовательность символов **\b**. Она совпадает не с символом, а с определенной позицией в строке. Также определяется метапоследовательность для любой позиции, не являющейся границей слова **\B**.

Программы, которые не различают якорные метасимволы для начала и конца слова, но поддерживают опережающую проверку, могут имитировать их при помощи опережающей проверки:

`(?<!\pL)(?=\pL)` - эквивалент позиции, являющейся границей слова **\b**

`(?<=\pL)(?!\pL)` - эквивалент позиции, не являющейся границей слова **\B**